# Workaround for receiving DATA messages when the app is completely TERMINATED. Flutter Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Am deveoping and app where i want when a device receives a notification, to store it in mysql database(run http request) to send the data into the database.

I cant send it straight with because i dont know which account's device is subscribed to that channel.

I tried onBackgroundservices and it works when the app is in foreground or background not when is completely terminated.Firebase wrote this in the documents that data messages cannot be handled when the app is terminated.

So is there any workaround. I doing research on BACKGROUND SERVICES to keep the app in background. But it seems like the android displays all background running apps on thr notification tray.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to perform some work in the background for a message, your easiest and and most straightforward solution is to immediately delegate that work to [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager), which will keep the app alive long enough for you to complete your work, or at least reschedule it so that it can complete in the near future.